# how do i process multiple lines from csv file to call a api in spring batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a **csv** file which contain

> 1,John,Smith,john@gmail.com
> 2,Sachin,Dave,sachin@gmail.com
> 3,Peter,Mark,peter@gmail.com
> 4,Martin,Smith,martin@gmail.com
> 5,Raj,Patel,raj@gmail.com
> 6,Virat,Yadav,virat@gmail.com
> 7,Prabhas,Shirke,prabhas@gmail.com
> 8,Tina,Kapoor,tina@gmail.com
> 9,Mona,Sharma,mona@gmail.com
> 10,Rahul,Varma,rahul@gmail.com

I want to call a api with first 5 rows in the processor and go on

```java
//my reader is

private Step firstChunkStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("First Chunk Step")
        . < StudentCsv, StudentAndResponseCsv > chunk(2)
        .reader(flatFileItemReader())
        .processor(firstItemProcessor)
        .writer(flatFileItemWriter())
        .build();
}
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader < StudentCsv > flatFileItemReader() {
    FlatFileItemReader < StudentCsv > flatFileItemReader =
        new FlatFileItemReader < StudentCsv > ();

    flatFileItemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(new File("C:\\Users\\mdtouhid.it\\Downloads\\Flat-File-Item-Reader-In-Action\\InputFiles\\students.csv")));

    DefaultLineMapper < StudentCsv > defaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper < StudentCsv > ();

    DelimitedLineTokenizer delimitedLineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    delimitedLineTokenizer.setNames("ID", "First Name", "Last Name", "email");
    delimitedLineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
    defaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(delimitedLineTokenizer);

    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper < StudentCsv > fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper < StudentCsv > ();
    fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(StudentCsv.class);
    defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);

    flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(defaultLineMapper);

    flatFileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    System.out.println("Inside Item flat file reader" + flatFileItemReader);

    return flatFileItemReader;
}

//my processor is

public class FirstItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor < StudentCsv, StudentAndResponseCsv > {

    @Autowired
    private ApiService apiService;

    @Override
    public StudentAndResponseCsv process(StudentCsv item) throws Exception {
        String response = apiService.restCallToGetFact();
        return studentAndResponseCsv;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The processor is designed to work on a single item, not the entire chunk.

What you can do is set the `chunkSize=5` and call the API in `ChunkListener#beforeWrite(Chunk chunk)`. This callback gives you a reference to the chunk of items to be written before actually them. This extension point can be used to perform the API call with a chunk of items.

Another option would be to encapsulate items in a wrapper type that is returned from the reader (ie the reader returns one an aggregate item at a time, containing 5 individual items).

Comment: Can you write me some code of second option

Comment: You can find an example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/multiline/AggregateItemReader.java